# Tcolorboxed Theorems

Tags: tcolorbox, theorems

I'd like to create something like that:

[image: Tcolorboxed Theorems]

The code for this photo

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


% (Re)newcommands

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
% New counters

\newcounter{boxtheorem}[subsection]
\newenvironment{boxtheorem}[1][]{\refstepcounter{boxtheorem}\par\medskip \textbf{Theorem --- \colorbox{orange} {\theboxtheorem.} #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]

% New Theorems 

\newcommand{\tcbnamedtheoremname}{
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!40,colframe=red]{
\newtheorem{tcbnamedtheoreminner}[boxtheorem]{\protect\tcbnamedtheoremname}
\newenvironment{tcbnamedtheorem}[1]
{%
\renewcommand{\tcbnamedtheoremname}{#1}%
\begin{tcbnamedtheoreminner}%
}
{\end{tcbnamedtheoreminner}}}
\end{tcolorbox}}

% My Book

\title{Theorem Proof, Stack}

\author{Name, Surname}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\Large
\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{Theorems}
\subsection{Colorboxed Theorems}

The \LaTeX--funcion in rows 19--26 makes this:

\begin{tcbnamedtheorem}{Cauchy--Lipschitz}
Statement.
\begin{proof}
Its Proof.
\end{proof}
\end{tcbnamedtheorem}

\flushleft{}But I'd like to have this:

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!40,colframe=red]
{\textbf{Theorem --- \colorbox{orange}{1.1.1.1.}}
Statement.}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{proof}
Its Proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

My goal is to create a new style of theorems using `tcolorbox`.

I don't understand where I wronged into creating the tex function.

**First Today's Edit:** "Overleaf" tells me that this code has three errors:

(1) Illegal parameter number in definition of \tcbnamedtheoremname. Main Tex, 31

(2) LaTeX Error: Environment tcbnamedtheorem undefined. Main Tex, 50

(3) LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{tcbnamedtheorem}. Main Tex, 55

I hope that with this edit my question is clearer.

Comment: Have you looked at chapter 18 about the theorems library in the [`tcolorbox` manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/tcolorbox/0)?

Comment: Yes. I must study this package. If I have other problems, could I write again? Please

Comment: If you can't make it work, update your question with your attempt, explaining where you get stuck.

Comment: Ok thank you so much

Comment: I edited my question. Could someone help me? Thanx

Comment: I didn't spot a \tcbuselibrary{theorems} in your code...do you need that?

Comment: Thanks but I solved it in another way

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what to do when there is a theorem title and where do you like to have the proof.

Here my examples:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} <-- no more needed
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% (Re)newcommands
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

% New Theorems 
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=subsection
    ]{tcbnamedtheorem}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    toptitle=2mm,
    colback=gray!40,colframe=red,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=gray!40,
    detach title,before upper={\tcbtitle\ },
    title={\textbf{Theorem --- \colorbox{orange}{\thetcbcounter.}}\ifstrempty{#2}{\ignorespaces}{~#2.}}, 
    #1
    }

% My Book

\title{Theorem Proof, Stack}

\author{Name, Surname}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{Theorems}
\subsection{Colorboxed Theorems}
Theorem with title and proof in the box
\begin{tcbnamedtheorem}{Cauchy--Lipschitz}
Statement.
\begin{proof}
Its Proof.
\end{proof}
\end{tcbnamedtheorem}
\noindent Theorem with title and proof out of the box
\begin{tcbnamedtheorem}{Cauchy--Lipschitz}
Statement.
\end{tcbnamedtheorem}
\begin{proof}
Its Proof.
\end{proof}
\noindent Theorem without title and proof in the box
\begin{tcbnamedtheorem}{}
Statement.
\begin{proof}
Its Proof.
\end{proof}
\end{tcbnamedtheorem}
\noindent Theorem without title and proof out of the box
\begin{tcbnamedtheorem}{}
Statement.
\end{tcbnamedtheorem}
\begin{proof}
Its Proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you, but I already solved it

Comment: @Puck do you know you can answer your own question?

Comment: I abbandoned this template for theorems: I completely changed template, but ever using tcolorbox. I created several templates with tcolorbox, non only for theorems, but for propositions, corollaries, ovìbservation, definitions, property, examples, exercises, too. You don't have to answer my question, thank you anyway.

Comment: @Puck For the future, please delete the question you don't need anymore, to avoid people wasting time answering. Thank you.